# Error Opening Queue, unrecognized error

Tags: msmq

I'm hoping someone will be able to help me with an issue we are having moving from Test to Production. In test everything is working fine but in Production we are having queue access problems.
Current configuration...

1. MSMQ queue server located on a work group machine located in DMZ
2. MSMQ message receiver machine located on a work group machine located off the internal domain
3. Wcf workflow services hosted in IIS on message receiver machine that monitor the MSMQ queue server
4. Private queues with names that match the end point of the Wcf workflow service and use the IP address of the queue server, i.e. net.msmq://[IP address]/private/workflowservice/service.xamlx
5. Net.MSMQ binding in IIS on receiving machine is configured to the IP address of the queue server
6. Net.MSMQ activator service on the receiving machine is running under NETWORK SERVICE
7. The receiving workflow services run using an application pool running under NETWORK SERVICE
8. ANONYMOUS LOGON and NETWORK SERVICE have full permissions on queues
9. MSMQ server Disable Unauthenticated RPC Calls is disabled
   MSMQ installed on both machines
10. Firewalls are configured to allow ingoing and outgoing on all MSMQ ports
    Can send to the queues successfully

If access one of the receiving workflow services via Internet Explorer I receive the following error message,
"An error occurred while opening the queue: Unrecognized error -1072824319 (0xc00e0001)."
I can see from the MSMQ Server machine security event log that the ANONYMOUS LOGON user is accessing the machine but the queue is not being recognised.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.